# llvmlite: Implementing an i64 array copy function

Tags: python, llvm, llvmlite

I'm trying to implement a copy function that receives two pointers to source and destination arrays and an integer representing their length:

```
fcopy = ir.FunctionType(ir.PointerType(integer), [ir.PointerType(integer), ir.PointerType(integer), integer])
copy = ir.Function(module, fcopy, name="copy")
copy_entry = copy.append_basic_block("copy_entry")
builder.position_at_end(copy_entry)

src, dst, cur_list_len = copy.args
src = builder.bitcast(src, ir.PointerType(integer))
dst = builder.bitcast(dst, ir.PointerType(integer))

cnt = integer(0)
cnt_ptr = builder.alloca(integer)
builder.store(cnt, cnt_ptr)

copy_loop = builder.append_basic_block("copy_loop")
builder.position_at_end(copy_loop)

with builder.if_then(
    builder.icmp_signed("<", builder.load(cnt_ptr), cur_list_len),
) as then:
    cnt = builder.load(cnt_ptr)    
    builder.store(  # Increment ptrs and copy from src to dst
        builder.load(builder.inttoptr(builder.add(builder.ptrtoint(src, integer), cnt), ir.PointerType(integer))),
        builder.inttoptr(builder.add(builder.ptrtoint(dst, integer), cnt), ir.PointerType(integer))
    )
    builder.store(builder.add(cnt, integer(1)), cnt_ptr)
    builder.branch(copy_loop)

builder.ret(dst)
```

This is the output:

```
define i64* @"copy"(i64* %".1", i64* %".2", i64 %".3")
{
copy_entry:
  %".5" = alloca i64
  store i64 0, i64* %".5"
copy_loop:
  %".7" = load i64, i64* %".5"
  %".8" = icmp slt i64 %".7", %".3"
  br i1 %".8", label %"copy_loop.if", label %"copy_loop.endif"
copy_loop.if:
  %".10" = load i64, i64* %".5"
  %".11" = ptrtoint i64* %".1" to i64
  %".12" = add i64 %".11", %".10"
  %".13" = inttoptr i64 %".12" to i64*
  %".14" = load i64, i64* %".13"
  %".15" = ptrtoint i64* %".2" to i64
  %".16" = add i64 %".15", %".10"
  %".17" = inttoptr i64 %".16" to i64*
  store i64 %".14", i64* %".17"
  %".19" = add i64 %".10", 1
  store i64 %".19", i64* %".5"
  br label %"copy_loop"
copy_loop.endif:
  ret i64* %".2"
}
```

but I keep getting this error:
RuntimeError: LLVM IR parsing error

```
<string>:10:1: error: expected instruction opcode
copy_loop:
^
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Was answered on the LLVM subreddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/LLVM/comments/xugi4j/llvmlite_implementing_a_copy_function_for_i64/

Comment: This is also one of the many, many questions that the LLVM Verifier answers. Verify early and often.